# Как написать программу обратного отсчета с помощью рекурсии?

Tags: ruby, рекурсия

Напишите программу, которая будет делать обратный отсчет от числа, которое вы ввели, к нулю с помощью цикла, а затем с помощью рекурсии.

С помощью цикла:

```
i=gets.chop.to_i
loop do
i-=1
puts "#{i}"
break if i==0
end

или

i=gets.chop.to_i
while i>0
  i-=1
  puts "#{i}"
end
```

С рекурсией не получается. (

Comment: @urasuper1994, Первое: чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Второе (по поводу рекурсии):

def fn(x):

Comment: Заголовок понравился.

    -- Правильно?
    -- Нет. Иначе Вы не задавали бы этот вопрос

Comment: @urasuper1994, а в чем проблема, не удается сравнить с нулем или вычесть единичку?

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы написать рекурсивную функцию, достаточно реализовать самый простой случай и вызвать саму функцию для реализации всего остального:

```
def countdown(n)
  if n > 0
    puts n
    countdown(n - 1)
  end
end
```

Пример использования:

```
countdown(gets.to_i)
```

Ещё одна итеративная версия:

```
def countdown_iter(n)
  n.downto(1) { |i| puts i }
end
```